# How to migrate from Google openid to Google+ Sign in?

Tags: openid, google-plus, lightopenid

I have been using Google openid on a website and therefore have lots of accounts in my database. They have usernames like `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOaadsfhaskjhfkjsahfkjsdhf`.

I want to migrate to Google+ sign-in, but I don't see how to recognize the matching openid accounts that already exist in my database.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should do:

1. Replace the existing OAuth flow to use the new Google+ Sign-in button. There are [a number of quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart) to make this easier for you. You authorize the user using the JavaScript client button and then pass the one-time-code to the server and perform an OAuth v2 code exchange.
2. When the user signs in with the new Google+ button, replace your existing credentials (e.g. refresh token) with the ones that are generated from the one-time-code flow.

You can match up the users when they sign in using the new button by using their ID from Google+ which should be the same as the identifier from the older (OAuth / Open ID) flow.